# Asteroid Movement - XNA Asteroids Clone

Tags: c#, xna

I've just started a XNA project and I want to make Asteroids by Atari in Monogame.  For the moment, I have the movement of the ship. I've just modified a few things in the code. The problem now is the asteroids. I'm trying to research of how to make them and I'm not having any good results.

My Code:

```
private Texture2D texture;
    private Rectangle destinationRectangle;
    private Rectangle sourceRectangle;
    private float rotationSpeed;
    private Vector2 rotationOrigin;
    private float rotationAngle;
    private float speed;
    private Vector2 velocity;

    public Asteroide(Texture2D texture, int x, int y)
    {

    }
    public Asteroide(Texture2D texture, int x, int y, int width, int height, float speed, float rotationSpeed)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed;
        destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
        sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        rotationOrigin = new Vector2(texture.Width * 0.5f, texture.Height * 0.5f);
        this.speed = speed;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int degree = rnd.Next(-45, 46);
        double radian = degree * Math.PI / 180;
        ChangeAngle(radian);

    }

    public void ChangeAngle(double radian)
    {
        velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(radian) * speed;
        velocity.Y = -1f * (float)Math.Sin(radian) * speed;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Move(gameTime);

    }
    private void Move(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        destinationRectangle.X += (int)(velocity.X * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
        destinationRectangle.Y += (int)(velocity.Y * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
    }
    private void Rotation(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        rotationAngle += rotationSpeed * (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White, rotationAngle, rotationOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
```

What I want is an asteroid that constantly moves and to generate asteroids of all sizes.  They should cover all the screen in big, medium and small sizes. I know I have to use a Random somewhere, but i don't know where.

Comment: Please explain the result you are getting and why it differs from the expected outcome

Comment: I'm getting one asteroid in a position and it goes forward and dissapears from the screen. What I want is ten asteroids that have random positions and generate randomly in the screen with different angle and directions.

Comment: Ok, you need to show all the relevant code, when in doubt check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, how are the asteroids being instanciated?